# How to locate the DXP files in library based on the content of Web Player temp folder

Tags: spotfire

My scenario is that I have a list of files with .DXP extension which are a temporary files stored in web player installation and are used for caching purposes.

I need to find which files are they in the library as they dont have their original names but just some autogenerated GUID or other ID and the extension.

Any clues ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to query the spotfire databases. This should be what you're looking for.

```
select 
    i.ITEM_ID
    ,i.TITLE
    ,i.DESCRIPTION
    ,i.CREATED
    ,CREATED_BY = u.DISPLAY_NAME
    ,CREATED_BY_USERNAME = u.USER_NAME
    ,i.MODIFIED
    ,t.LABEL 
    ,t.DISPLAY_NAME
from 
    LIB_ITEMS i
inner join
    LIB_ITEM_TYPES t on 
    t.TYPE_ID = i.ITEM_TYPE
inner join
    USERS u on 
    u.USER_ID = i.CREATED_BY
order by
    i.ITEM_ID
```

Comment: I have verified and it is not giving the same IDs.

Comment: I’ll look deeper @JacekSierajewski

Comment: sorry i can't test further because i don't have any files in that temp folder

Comment: I think those files are created by Scheduled updates. But it might be the case you use SU and defined to store those files in the different location.

Comment: I think those files wont get created at all as long as you have a free memory. Once the memory gets finished then Spotfire starts to create the files in question